# Sorting / orderby ascending on basis of two variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, sorting, angularjs-orderby

I have a condition in which, I need to sort the list according to two values in ascending order.

First according to SCHEDSTART, if this is available
If this is blank then with WONUM

div with the SCHEDSTART should be on top.

code written by me which is not working:

code 1: 
HTML:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="wo in vm.workOrders | orderBy : dynamicOrder>
```

controller:

```
function dynamicOrder(wo){
            if(wo.json.SCHEDSTART){
                return wo.json.SCHEDSTART;
            }else{
                return wo.json.WONUM;
            }
        }
```

code 2:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="wo in vm.workOrders | orderBy : ['json.SCHEDSTART','json.WONUM']>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the `workOrders` array?

Answer (score 1):

Idk if this is the best way but my recommendation is create two `ion-item` tags with an `ng-if` on each of them. For example

```
<ion-item ng-if="SCHEDSTART" ng-repeat="wo in vm.workOrders | orderBy : SCHEDSTART>
```

and

```
<ion-item ng-if="!SCHEDSTART" ng-repeat="wo in vm.workOrders | orderBy : WONUM>
```

`ng-if` operates on true/false and [truthy/falsy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) so if SCHEDSTART is `truthy`, or in other words has content, then the first html tag I showed will populate your DOM.

If SCHEDSTART is `falsy`, or in other words is `0 (zero)`, `"" (empty string)`, `null`, `undefined`, or `NaN (Not a number)` Then the first tag will look like this in the DOM

```
<!--ng-if="SCHEDSTART"-->
```

Now if you want to be extra extra sure that this works, you can create a variable specifically for dictating whether SCHEDSTART is truthy or not. 
Using your code you provided I would change it as such

```
var schedStartHasData;

function dynamicOrder(wo){
        if(wo.json.SCHEDSTART){
            schedStartHasData = true;
        }else{
            schedStartHasData = false;
        }
    }
```

And your two tags in your view would look like so

```
<ion-item ng-if="schedStartHasData " ng-repeat="wo in vm.workOrders | orderBy : SCHEDSTART>
```

and

```
<ion-item ng-if="!schedStartHasData" ng-repeat="wo in vm.workOrders | orderBy : WONUM>
```